# React js обратное преобразование кода

Tags: reactjs

Существуют ли способы сделать код react приложения после build пригодным к дальнейшей работе? Может не в исходном, но в пригодном

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходников нет и код минифицирован, то остается только сделать код более читаемым. Например можно воспользоваться этим сервисом - http://jsbeautifier.org/